# How do I set up ssmtp for use with Fastmail?

Tags: ssmtp

There are plenty of guides on the web about setting up [ssmtp](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/ssmtp) for Gmail, but it's a bit different for different providers.

How should it be done for [fastmail.com](http://fastmail.com)?

Answer (score 2):

After installing ssmtp (`sudo apt install ssmtp` is all it takes), go to *Password & Security* settings, and create an *App Password*. It only needs permission for SMTP, nothing else.

Then, edit `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` to resemble the following:

```
root=username@fastmail.com
AuthUser=username@fastmail.com
AuthPass=passwordGoesHere123
mailhub=smtp.fastmail.com:465
hostname=fastmail.com
FromLineOverride=NO
UseTLS=YES
UseSTARTTLS=NO
```

Replace `username@fastmail.com` with your actual Fastmail email address (which may not be `@fastmail.com`, but one of their other domain names) and use the App Password you created above for `AuthPass`.